# Spinner Value is not updated on the List View

Tags: android

I have a spinner that let user choose a meal from a set of string array in xml. After the user selected the item, I put the selection into the database, and display on a Listview.

In my model, I have a toString(),

```
@Override
public String toString() {

    return id + " " + note +"\n meal: " + this.meal;
}
```

In the controller class for editing the the meal, I have this,

```
    public class EditNoteFragment extends Fragment implements
    OnItemSelectedListener{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit,
            container, false);

    // populating the spinner with string array of time category
    spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_meal_category);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.array.meal_array,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
   }

        @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {
        meal = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Got the meal: " + meal);

}  


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // I added the field variable meal into the datebase in this block of code
            //note.setMeal(meal.toString());
}

    }
```

I used log to verified that I got the user choice and stored in the field variable "meal" in my class, but when I run the application and the list displays meal as null.

I am certain that I have successfully added the meal into the database.

Here is the view class

```
            public static class NoteFragment extends ListFragment {
    TextView tx_list_note;
    NoteDataSource datasource;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        datasource = new NotesDataSource(getActivity());
        datasource.open();

        List<Note> notes = datasource.findAll();
        if (notes.size() == 0) {
            createData();
            notes = datasource.findAll();           
                      }

        ArrayAdapter<Note> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Note>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes,
                container, false);


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

in fragment_notes.xml, I have one single listview in the relative layout

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    >
  </ListView>
```

Thank you very much for you help in advance. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any list view related code.

Comment: I added the view related code. Thanks

Comment: I find the problem. It turns out my database was not successfully wired with the meal. Everything else is working. Thanks very much for the help.